# how to get summation of pair(key) values in a map in java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a map which represents a matrix of string-int that maps to a value:
`static Map<Pair<String,Integer>, Integer> wordTopic = new HashMap<>();`

I want to get the summation of values that has a specific string (a part of the pair) not the whole pair `Pair<String,Integer>` AKA the summation of one row.

Example:  the matrix

`string/int  1           2 
value1      13            26
value2      11            22`

i want the summation of row values of string "value1"  ..output should be =39

I have found this: `Integer integerSum = wordTopic.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();`

but this will get me the summation of the values of the whole key AKA the whole matrix ,i want the summation of the row only..any hints?

Comment: Hint: Use a `filter` intermediate operation.

Comment: WordTopic.keySet()...

Comment: what does keySet() do ? i mean how it specifies which in the pair to use ? @nitnamby

Comment: can you give and example of the input/output? Your question is not quite clear enough.

Comment: you did the input/output example i wanted @user2023577 thank you all!

Comment: @Abdel-RahmanEl-Feraly: then the selected answer is wrong, isn't it... I strongly suggest you add it to your question.

Comment: the selected answer, adds the values in the row giving the string..wait i misunderstood your example..u are grouping each row ..i just wanted a specific row summation not all the rows in groups..my bad buddy. @user2023577

Comment: add an example for input/output ? okay

Comment: Your 3 row 3 column matrix doesn't clarify what we would expect in the input map.in terms of key=value rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function as such:

```
int getSummationOfValuesByKey(Map<Pair<String,Integer>, Integer> map, String key) {
          return map.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(e -> e.getKey().getKey().equals(key))
                    .mapToInt(Map.Entry::getValue)
                    .sum();
}
```

which given a map and a key will return the summation of the values where the Pair's key is equal to the provided key.

Answer (score 1):

I presume this:

Input:

```
a-1 = 100
a-2 = 200
b-4 = 400
b-8 = 800
```

Output:

```
a = 300
b = 1200
```

Using map.entries() will probably help deal with the row more easily.

You seem to want to group by strings first, so a .group() lambda examining the Map.Entry.getKey().getValue0() would make a map of `<String, List<Map.Entry>>`

and for each one of those, you would do the desired .map & .sum, etc (left as homework...)

You can probably tell that a good old for loop with another hashmap is going to be more readable...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Pair is as follows.

```
public class Pair<T, U> {

    public final T first;
    public final U second;

    public static <T, U> Pair<T, U> of(T first, U second) {
        return new Pair<>(first, second);
    }

    public Pair(T first, U second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

}
```

Then how about:

```
    String wordToFilterFor = "abc";
    Integer integerSum = wordTopic.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().first.equals(wordToFilterFor))
            .map(e -> e.getValue())
            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

Basically start the Stream with the entrySet, so that you have access to the Pair kay.  Then filter for the Pair's word.